# EF 6 Plus - How To Do Future Raw Query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I am using this [EF 6 PLUS](https://entityframework.net/ef-plus) library, and I am trying to do future raw query, something like this

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<SomeClass>("query here").Future();
```

but there is not such option in this library, I also tried using `DeferredFirst()`, `DeferredSingle()` of this library but no luck, those methods don't let me insert raw queries.

How can I achieve this with this library or another one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Future` and all methods like `DeferredFirst` are extension methods on `IQueryable<T>`:

```cs
public static QueryFutureEnumerable<T> Future<T>(this IQueryable<T> query)
```

`Database.SqlQuery` returns `DbRawSqlQuery<T>`, which implements `IEnumerable<T>`, not `IQueryable<T>`, so the extension doesn't apply. There's no way to execute `SqlQuery`s in one `Future` batch with other queries.

You can alleviate some of the "pain" by opening the context's connection before executing a mix of queries and closing it afterwards. That prevents EF from closing and opening the connection for each individual query it executes. It's not the same as executing queries in deferrable batches, but it may add some efficiency.

```cs
try
{
    context.Database.Connection.Open();
    ...
}
finally
{
    context.Database.Connection.Close();
}
```